# Get captured variables from lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I was wondering, if there's a way to get the types/values of the captured variables of a lambda? - The usage scenario would be something alike;

```
int a = 5;
auto lamb = [a](){ return a; };
static_assert(std::is_same<typename get_capture_type<0>(lamb)::type, int>::value, "");
assert(get_capture_value<0>(lamb) == 5)
```

Note: `get_capture_*<N>(lambda)` should obviously result in a compiler error, when `N > #captured_variables`.

What I need is actually just a way to access the captures somehow, if possible. That is, I can do the template meta-programming myself.

Comment: Should `a` in the final two lines actually be `lamb`?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: That usage scenario doesn't sound like anything any real code would ever need.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, syntax was thought to be along the lines of `std::get<I>(tuple)`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Several possibility spring into mind; debugging is one, also whenever a feature is available one can sometimes find good ways of using it. - Also I'm generally just interested in if it's possible.

Comment: IALZFBVPÄGÄAIGHNIPPLESALADS. ARGH! I'll repeat from my comment in the other thread: ***lambdas are not special, don't do special things just for them***.

Comment: I don't know. My debugger can handle lambdas just fine. Regarding the general interest, no, it's not possible: lambdas are designed to be as not-special as possible (that's a feature). They're just regular objects for pretty much all purposes *except writing them*.

Comment: @Xeo: I do believe there's a difference, namely in the fact that the captured members are anonymous, and one cannot simply apply something alike BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT, as one could with a object functor.

Comment: @Skeen: How is that different from not being able to peek into the private variables of the function object I hand you?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Your debugger may be able to handle lambdas just fine, but having the `get_capture_type<I>`, would allow you to do static_assertions on the captured types, however I guess one could just explicitly specify the variables to capture. (That is in order to assert that only certain variables are captured/accessed inside the lambda). Also I guess one cannot assume anything about the order of the captured variables?

Comment: There are no captured variables. There's an object with stuff in it. (You know, like any other object)

Comment: @Rapptz That's not a comment - it's an answer. Or I should say, that's *the* answer.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I know that lambdas are essentially just function objects, but then let me extend the scope of my comment: Is being able to do static_assertions on whether an object has a specific member a bad idea? - and if it isn't, why shouldn't I be able to do that on lambdas as well as any other object?

Comment: Why would private members make any difference outside of the class itself? The outside world has no business making assertions about my implementation details. Isn't that what public vs private is all about?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Clearly you didn't get the point of my comment. If captured variables are indeed private then, the answer to my main question is; "it's not possible", however the question I asked here, was whether being able to query information about specific members is a bad idea? - Also you will only hide members with private if there's no reason for anyone else to see them, however if there is, then they should be public? - So if it did make sense to be able to check the types/values of the captured variables, then they should be public, and hence accessible by such a mechanism?

Comment: @Skeen: Let me turn that question around: do you have any use case in which knowing what was captured matters? The whole purpose of a lambda or a bound object or a functor is the interface that it implements, how can it be called. What it does when called does not matter for the user. If you need to check an argument, don't capture it, pass it as an argument, have the caller test it and then use it to call the lambda. (Or alternatively write your own functor and provide the access you want)

Comment: OKay, this is fixed now :)

Comment: @mlvljr What is fixed? when/where?

Comment: @underscore_d I forgot :) ah, wait, I think, this was downvoted into minuses, so I proposed a bounty -- which worked. Freak them downvoters :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible *by design*

> **5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]**
>   15 [...] For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. [...]
>   16 [...] It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference.

Captured variables are unnamed (or at least have names that are unspeakable by mortals) and their declaration order is deliberately unspecified. By-reference captures *may not even exist* in the closure type.

You don't want to do this anyway. You may think you do, but you don't really.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

No. C++ has no reflection, and that means it doesn't have reflection on lambda's either.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, this might not be possible because lambda fields are *unnamed*.

You could write your own function object, though. A struct with the fields you'd capture and an `operator()`.

In your case, i suspect the following would work:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

struct mylambda {
    int a;
    int operator()() { return a; }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    auto lamb = mylambda{a};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(lamb.a), int>::value, "");
    assert(lamb.a == 5);
    return 0;
}
```