# Access C++14 lambda captures like struct members

Tags: c++, lambda, capture, c++14

AFAIK, C++11/14 does not allow in-place definition of a new return type while defining a lambda. However, it seems a C++14 lambda capture expression essentially creates an anonymous type with one or more "members" and an operator (). So, why is that the compiler does not allow access to the captured members from **outside** the lambda. My feeble mind cannot handle the complexities of C++ but does it sound like a reasonable language extension to you? Here is an example.

```
vector<string> words = { "Stack", "Overflow" };
auto l = [w = words](){}; // almost like a C# anonymous type
cout << l.w[0]; // does not work.
```

Comment: *"AFAIK, C++11/14 does not allow in-place definition of a new type while defining a lambda."* What do you mean? Inside the lambda-capture or inside the lambda-body?

Comment: I mean to say more like a new return type.

Comment: AFAIK, there are anonymous local classes in C++ `vector<string> words = { "Stack", "Overflow" }; struct { decltype(words) w; } l{words}; cout << l.w[0];` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95fc5770a6a0036d)

Comment: @Live example: The issue is that the anonymous local classes can't be used in an expression. For instance, right when calling a function.

Comment: You can pass them to function templates. Lambdas have the same "restriction": Each lambda-expression is of a *unique* type, i.e `auto x = []{ return 42; }; auto y = []{ return 42; };` <-- `x` and `y` have different types.

Comment: Of course it shouldn't work. Data members ought to be private!

Comment: @n.m. That's reasonable if the type is exposed outside a "module". In a local context (e.g., within an expression, a function, or even a class), I would prefer to use public members.

Comment: Given that I've never seen anyone else asking for this, I estimate that the desire for this ability is minuscule, probably because it would break the semantics and encapsulation of lambdas, just because you don't want to spend a couple of minutes writing your own `struct` with `public` members and an `operator()`.

Comment: @underscore_d With range-v3 style data processing, creating an anonymous type on the fly would be very handy. std::pair, std::tuple does not cut it because we (humans) need readable member names. C# anonymous types were added for a reason in that language. Very handy in fluent, functional apis.

Answer (score 17):

**The status quo**

This was discussed when lambda *init-captures* were added to the language. The current working draft of the standard (N3797) says (in **[expr.prim.lambda]p11**):

> For every *init-capture* a non-static data member named by the *identifier* of the *init-capture* is declared in the closure type.

The standard does *not* specify the access of that member, making it unclear whether this is valid:

```
auto x = [n(0)] {};
int k = x.n; // ok?
```

This and some other specification problems with *init-captures* led to national body comment GB3 on the standard draft, which is handled by the C++ core working group as [core issue 1760](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1760). In discussion of that issue, the core working group decided that the lambda's *init-captures* should *not* be accessible members of the closure object.

The resolution for issue 1760 (which is approved by CWG but not yet by the full committee) changes the specification to instead say:

> An *init-capture* behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form `“auto init-capture ;”` whose declarative region is the *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement* [...]

This new wording makes it clear that the *init-capture* does not add a nameable member of the closure object, and it instead acts like any other lambda capture.

**As a language extension**

Making *init-captures* be accessible members of the closure type is certainly possible (and my initial implementation of *init-captures* in clang did that, before I implemented the resolution of issue 1760). It also seems like a useful feature, but it would also allow violation of the encapsulation of *lambda-expressions* in the common case where the *init-captures* should not be visible.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding this right, you want to be able to access a variable that is captured within a lambda. But according to the top answer on [Get captured variables from lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976680/1508519), it's not possible.

> It's not possible *by design*
>
> > 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]
> >
> > 15 [...] For each entity captured by copy, **an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.** The declaration order of these members is unspecified. [...]
> >
> > 16 [...] It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are
> >     declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference.
>
> **Captured variables are unnamed (or at least have names that are
>   unspeakable by mortals)** and their declaration order is deliberately
>   unspecified. By-reference captures *may not even exist* in the closure
>   type.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Sigh! I wish it was an accessible named non-static member in case of by-copy capture.

Comment: As I said in the quoted answer, you don't really want that, you only think you do. Supporting what you want would restrict implementations and prevent optimisations. If you want access to named members then **don't use a lambda expression!**