# C++ lambda capture single struct field by value

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have a large struct and want to capture a field out of it by value.

The below code apparently WORKS, but I was confused and led to believe by [this (from SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390608/access-c14-lambda-captures-like-struct-members) that it shouldn't. Have I misunderstood that post, or will this fail in some way I do not see?

I am using C++14.

```
struct Foo { int Bar; /* ... */ };
Foo foo;
IAcceptStdFunction( [Bar = foo.Bar]{ /* can use Bar */ } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such `Bar` from inside the lambda without any troubles. Just note that it's a copy of the original `foo.Bar`, not a reference.

The post you linked talks about a situation when we want to look what a specific lambda has captured without actually calling it, some kind of introspection.