# Is it possible to find the number/type of the captured variables in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Is it possible to automatically realize the number of the variables captured by the lambda when accessed by value or by reference? Also is it possible to decipher their types? For example, assume this piece of code:

```
int a = 47;
int b = 48;
long long c = 49;
auto f1 = [=](){ return a + b; };
auto f2 = [=](){ return a + b + c; };
```

Is it possible to have a function named `count_args` that returns `2` in a line and `3` in the next line if called like below?

```
std::cout << count_args( f1 ) << "\n" << count_args( f2 );
```

Comment: I highly doubt it. Is there a particular problem you have in mind that benefits from doing it this way?

Comment: Some highly unportable solution is to use sizeof. It will gives 4 and 8 in ideone:  http://ideone.com/GFNlpD

Comment: @chris Recently having lambda expressions have become possible in CUDA. For a template library I design, I would need to know the types and the arguments a user-defined lambda access so that I can allocate shared memory for each and every one of them (an in-kernel shared memory allocation requires its type and its length to be specified at compile time).

Comment: @Farzad, all I think is possible is `sizeof(f1)` to allocate memory for the whole function

Comment: Read also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390608/access-c14-lambda-captures- like-struct-members

Comment: @PiotrNycz Thanks. Also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19963041/2386951) was linked in the same page.

Comment: Lets say, you have this `struct X { T a, b; U c; };`. Now the question is like asking `count_args(X)`. In my opinion that is not possible without reflection, whether you setup the reflection ability yourself, or C++ adds this feature as core language feature.

Comment: @Nawaz correct. It's actually one of the answers in the link I provided.

Comment: Optmization would at least do this:
`f1` returns `95`, `f2` returns `144`. Hence counting the captured variables doesn't makes sense, and would be highly non-portable, even with same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the question implicitly assumes that captured variables are in fact member variables. The compiler is however granted far more latitude. As Ajay notes in the comments, a decent optimizer can replace members by hoisted expressions, and it also may alter types, use non-C++ types, etcetera. So you may capture `struct color { char R,G,B }` while the lambda actually stores `.R` and `.G` only. Is `count_args` now 2/3rd ?

Comment: `(2 + i)/3` naturally (or `(2 - j)/3` for electrical engineers)

Comment: I am aware of "constant propagation" as a compiler optimization, and I know that a C++ compiler should/would do that, as @Ajay pointed out. Maybe it was better I had clarified assuming the captured variables are not optimized away.